# Is this computation of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} x^x $ rigorous enough?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} x^x $

For every $x\in (0,1)$ there exists $n_x\in \mathbb N$ such that

$\dfrac 1{n_x+1}\lt x\lt \dfrac 1{n_x}$

It follows that $n_x\to \infty$ as $x\to 0^+$ (Refer **Note**)

$\displaystyle x^{\frac 1{n_x}}\lt x^x\lt x^{\frac 1{n_x+1}}\implies \left({\frac 1{n_x+1}}\right)^{\frac 1{n_x}}\lt x^x\lt \left(\frac{1}{n_x}\right)^{\frac 1{n_x+1}}$ and using $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n^{\frac 1n}\to 1$ it follows by squeeze theorem that $x^x\to 1$ as $x\to 0^+$.

**Note:**  $(x\to 0^+)\implies \forall\delta\gt 0\, \exists x \gt 0\, x\lt \delta$ and by Archemedean property it follows that $\exists (n_x+1)\in \mathbb N\,\left(\dfrac 1{n_x+1}\lt \delta\right)\implies n_x+1\gt \dfrac 1\delta\\\implies n_x+1\to \infty\;\text{ as }\;\delta\gt 0\;\text{ is arbitrary.}$

Is the above enough if I don't want to use L'Hospital's rule or logarithm? Thanks.

Comment: If you can take for granted that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}=1$, then you can just do the change of variables $y=\frac1x$ and obtain $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac1{y^{1/y}}$. I don't quite see what the reduction to an integer sequence accomplishes, exactly, if the goal is to avoid $\log$.

Comment: $\frac 1{n_x+1}\lt x\lt \frac 1{n_x}$ should be replaced by $\frac 1{n_x+1}\leq x\lt \frac 1{n_x}$ or $\frac 1{n_x+1}\lt x\leq \frac 1{n_x}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Ah! Those fine details! Noted. I somehow forgot that. Thanks a lot sir. :)

Comment: Since the statement $x^{\frac1{n_x}}<x^x<x^{\frac1{n_x+1}}$ appears out of nowhere, you only asserted the implication "if $x^{\frac1{n_x}}<x^x<x^{\frac1{n_x+1}}$ then $\left(\frac1{n_x+1}\right)^{\frac1{n_x}}<x^x<\left(\frac1{n_x}\right)^{\frac1{n_x+1}}$" and not actually proved $\left(\frac1{n_x+1}\right)^{\frac1{n_x}}<x^x<\left(\frac1{n_x}\right)^{\frac1{n_x+1}}$ is true.  C.f. "(it follows that) $0,1,2\in\mathbb{N}$, $2=1\implies 0=1$".

Comment: @Gae.S.: I have not taken that for granted. The idea is this: knowing functions which are defined on positive integer variables (sequences), it can be proven that $n^{\frac 1n}\to 1$ using Binomial theorem. So using that it should be possible to find the limit in question. Note that $x$ here does not have to be an integer.

Comment: It is much simpler to use the identity $\log x\leq x-1$ and prove that $(1/x)\log x\to 0$ as $x\to\infty $ which is equivalent to your limit.

Comment: @Gae.S. I recall way back in undergrad, I covered $n^{1/n}\to 1$ when I learned sequences, which I learned before knowing what a continuous function / continuous limit was

Comment: @user10354138: I forgot to clarify that in post but I assure you that the statement didn't come out of nowhere. Since $a\in (0,1)$, the exponential function $a^y$ is decreasing. That's what I had in mind.

Comment: Your approach looks fine by the way.

Comment: While solving an exercise to prove:For $x\gt 0, $ $x^{r+s}=x^r x^s$ for any real $r,s$ of course barring weird situations when denominator is $0$, I realized that I had mostly taken law of exponents for granted because by definition $x\gt 0, $ $x^{r+s}=x^r x^s$ is defined for integers and then by extension it is proven for rationals (so far things are fine) and then for any real number (currently I'm trying to prove this). This made me re-work the limit in question using only positive integers.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I wonder why you need $x^x\to 1$ for that exercise. If at all you should need $a^x\to 1$ which makes the exponential function $a^x$ continuous.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I remembered $x^x\to 1$ from earlier  but while solving the exercise on law of exponents, I recalled that limit and tried to prove it (took a detour!) using positive integers. Of course, $x^x\to 1$ has nothing to do with the exercise, I think.